# How to differentiate StoreApps from Other Normal Apps?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, windows-store-apps, tasklist

When some application are running how can we differentiate whether it is storepps or other normal apps.
When we type `tasklist /apps` in powershell or command prompt,windows will gives us all the storeapps running,how windows is differentiating it from normal apps??

Comment: [IsImmersiveProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isimmersiveprocess).